# Is there a way to see how many users are currently connected to Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support

I was curious to know when most users connect to Ask Ubuntu during the day.

I am not sure if I am blind or if this function does not exist (because it is probably not useful to the majority of users).

But I was wondering if this was possible or the reason why it does not exist ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think there's anything other than the stats on http://stackexchange.com/sites